# How to get (childless) “tabs” in a pygtk application

Tags: python, tabs, pygtk

I am facing the problem to need tabs in a pygtk app. Pretty much just like gedit has, but without any per-child widget content.
I’ve come across [gtk.Notebook](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtknotebook.html), but that requires me to put a widget for each tab, which I don't want.

The reason is, that I have one widget, but would only like to updates its content based on which tab is selected.

Any hints on how to do that?
My idea so far would be to just add some invisible widget for each tab and then connect to the `select-page` signal. Which widget could I use as invisible widget, or is there a better/alternative way of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invisble widget idea works. But not with `gtk.Invisible` (this just crashes), but with `gtk.HBox()` or any other thing that seems empty.

```
self.notebook.append_page(gtk.HBox(), gtk.Label("title"))
```

Now if I want to display stuff *inside* the tab actually, I can use reparent to move the widget to the current tab like this.

```
class Tab(gtk.HBox):
    def __init__(self, child):
        self.child = child

self.notebook.append_page(Tab(myWidget), gtk.Label("title"))

def pageSelected(self, notebook, page, pagenum):
    box = notebook.get_nth_page(pagenum)
    box.child.reparent(box)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have global widgets, one per tab as you want, in order to access them easily when the tab is selected.

```
    self.notebook.append_page(self.rightBox,    gtk.Label("Orders"))
```

Then connect to the "switch page" signal

```
    self.notebook.connect("switch-page", self.pageSelected)
```

and :

```
def pageSelected(self, notebook, page, pagenum):
    name = notebook.get_tab_label(notebook.get_nth_page(pagenum))
```

Now you have "name" with the label of the currently selected page. Just test it (if name == "Orders" ...) to interact.

Hope this was of some help !

Comment: So when I’d add self.rightBox multiple times to the notebook, I get the warning `GtkWarning: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent` besides that stuff breaks if I display `rightBox` somewhere also (though I could live with it being displayed inside the notebook). Are you sure this works?

Comment: Absolutely, I use it for many big programs. But I only add self.rightbox once, and create other Hboxes and VBoxes to do it.

Comment: Then you probably misunderstood my question. I want the very same widget in every tab. But I found the answer after some experiments. So thanks for the effort!